Can't webpack's splitchunks.cacheGroup.name option use placeholders?
I used splitchunks, and hope that when the build content changes, the name of the webpack chunk will also change accordingly. the configuration is as follows：
module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  ...,
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    chunkIds: "named",
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        antd: {
          chunks: "all",
          test: /antd/,
          name: "antd.[chunkhash]",
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    }
  }
}

howover, the results obtained are not as expected.
The obtained dist directory file name is: antd.[chunkhash].72f43fcd3825cb3fe514.js,
and the content is:
(self["webpackChunkmy_react_webpack_project"] = self["webpackChunkmy_react_webpack_project"] || []).push([["antd.[chunkhash]"],{ ... })

Does the splitchunks name option not support placeholders? If so, how do I get a build-related chunk name?
